# Apache rewrite - optional parameters?

Tags: apache-2.2, rewrite

I'm creating SEO friendly urls for my news page.

My links look like this :

www.site.com/1234/the-pretty-url-string/

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /news.php?sid=$1&url=$2 [L]

This works great, but I like to have more flexability.

I want to be able to accept urls like :

www.site.com/1234

www.site.com/1234/

so then I can do some php $GET's and figure out if anything is missing - and 301 to the proper URL of my choice. I would like the &url=$2 to be optional.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+))?/?$ /news.php?sid=$1&url=$2 [L]
```

Comment: hmm .. no luck with that. I test different url's and nothing parsed.

Comment: I edited my original answer after testing it :).  Let me know if that works for you.